# access denied when i want to open up file

Tags: android, xamarin

in xamarin android
why access is denied when i want to BufferedStream my file?

```
fileAddress= "/storage/emulated/0/Download/rename2.pdfl";

Reader = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(fileAddress));
```

i granted read and write access in my manifest file.

when i open a file using FilePicker.PickAsync()  dont have any problem.
i know that FilePicker.PickAsync() cach my file before opening it.

how can i simulate that?

Comment: When you use FilePicker the user is implicitly granting permission for your app to read the file

Comment: yes, true. and what can i do now? i have a direct address to the file. and BufferedStream says access denied

Comment: i found it. on android 11 add this to manifest   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>   and then add this on code if access is denied         private void RequestStorageAccess()
        {
            if (!Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageManager)
            {
                StartActivityForResult(new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageAllFilesAccessPermission), 3);
            }
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment:

For Android 11, add this to manifest

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Add this if access is denied

```cs
private void RequestStorageAccess()
{
  if (!Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageManager) 
  {
    StartActivityForResult(
        new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageAllFilesAccessPermission),
        3);
  }
}
```